# Push Upgrades to subscribers of managed package 1GP using SF CLI

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, push-upgrade, 1gp-package

We can create a new version of my 1GP using `sf package1 version create...` in my CICD pipeline.

After sometime looking into the documentation of CLIs (sf and sfdx), I don't see any option to **push an upgrade to subscribers** of a 1GP managed.

I have only found this [option using the SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/push_upgrade_use_api.htm).

### Question:

Is any way to schedule the push upgrade using the cli (or build a bash/python script) do do it?